# git push mirror/all to new server causes all brances to be failed, but pushing single branches works

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I try to push an existing repository to a new remote. Pushing single branches using

```
git push newremote somebranch
```

works perfectly fine. However, when I try to push all branches at once using `--all` or `--mirror` all branches which have not been pushed to the new repo fail with no description other than `failed`:

```
git push -v -v --progress --mirror xxxxxxx
Pushing to xxxxxxx
Enumerating objects: 1942, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1431/1431), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (710/710), done.
Writing objects: 100% (966/966), 45.17 MiB | 5.72 MiB/s, done.
Total 966 (delta 552), reused 407 (delta 118), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (552/552), completed with 117 local objects.
To xxxxxxx
 = [up to date]        dev -> dev
 = [up to date]        main -> main
 ! [remote rejected]   feature/closebutton -> feature/closebutton (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   feature/poweruser -> feature/poweruser (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   fix/camcrash -> fix/camcrash (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   fix/uitweaks -> fix/uitweaks (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   release/v5 -> release/v5 (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   test/test -> test/test (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   v10 -> v10 (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   v12 -> v12 (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   v15 -> v15 (failed)
 ! [remote rejected]   v9 -> v9 (failed)
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/xxxx/dev'
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/xxxx/main'
error: failed to push some refs to 'xxxxxxx'
```

(this is a shortened version, the repo has dozens of branches)

The new remote is a github repo, the old remote is a bitbucket repo, if that helps. What is the problem here?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly `git push xxxxxxx feature/closebutton` for instance? What sort of access controls, if any, did you set on GitHub?

Comment: Works perfectly fine. So I could manually push all branches, but I'm puzzled why it doesn't work for all

Comment: That is indeed odd. You might consider asking GitHub support about this: maybe their fancy access controls have a limit on how many branch names are allowed in one `git push`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by cloning the source repo into a new folder and then pushing the freshly cloned to the new remote.

```
git clone myrepo
cd myrepo
git remote add newremote xxxxxxx
git push --progress --mirror xxxxxxx
```

Then I went to my local repo and pushed all branches, which worked fine now.